# Renaming multiple paired files, deleting varying barcode character string in middle?

Tags: shell-script, awk

I have a bunch of paired files with unneeded barcode tags within the middle of the file, for example:

```
LIB008983_TRA00020080_TAAGGCGA-TATCCTCT_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020080_TAAGGCGA-TATCCTCT_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020081_TAAGGCGA-AGAGTAGA_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020081_TAAGGCGA-AGAGTAGA_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020082_TAAGGCGA-GTAAGGAG_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020082_TAAGGCGA-GTAAGGAG_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020083_TAAGGCGA-ACTGCATA_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020083_TAAGGCGA-ACTGCATA_L001_R2.fastq.gz
```

I need to get rid of the barcode (which varies throughout the files) without modifying identifiers at the beginning or end of the file.

I have tried writing a script myself from what I've read online, but it appears to be a relatively poor attempt:

```
for f in LIB008983_TRA000{19916..20167}_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz;
do
  newName=${f/_*_\ _L001_R*.fastq.gz}
  mv -i "$f" "$newName";
done
```

here's the error message I get:

```
mv: cannot stat ‘LIB008983_TRA00019917_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz’: No such file or directory
```

Ideally, my final file name would be, for example:

```
LIB008983_TRA00020136_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020136_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020137_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020137_L001_R2.fastq.gz
..
..
```

and so on

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to Unix StackExchange.  I hope someone can answer your question.  However please note that images of text typically aren't the best way to present information.  Please see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text.  If you can update your question with text rather than images then it'll help both you and people after you looking for a similar answer.

Comment: @StephenHarris thanks I updated the question with text!

Comment: Better, but not quite :-)  There's still one screenshot of the script.  You can `cat` that file and cut'n'paste the results.   Thanks!

Comment: I THOUGHT THE COLORS WOULD HELP. replaced with text thanks.

Comment: The advantage of leaving it as text is that people looking to answer the question can cut'n'paste your code onto their machine for testing.   I've modified your question slightly for formatting reasons.  Thanks for performing the updates!

Comment: gotcha makes sense, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem you're seeing here is that the `for` loop is expanding in ways you're not expecting.  The `{...}` range operator is giving a complete list of all possible filenames, not just the ones that exist.

For example, file 19917 doesn't exist, causing that `mv` error message.

You can see this by putting an `echo` in the loop:

```
for f in LIB008983_TRA000{19916..20167}_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
do
  echo "$f"
done
```

This gives output like:

```
LIB008983_TRA00019916_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00019917_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00019918_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
...
LIB008983_TRA00020078_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020079_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020080_TAAGGCGA-TATCCTCT_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020080_TAAGGCGA-TATCCTCT_L001_R2.fastq.gz
...
LIB008983_TRA00020084_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020085_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020086_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
```

All those lines with `*` in them represent files that don't exist.

There's two ways to solve this.  Firstly, if you want to keep the range then put a test around the `mv`:

```
  if [ -f "$f" ]
  then
    mv -i "$f" "$newName"
  fi
```

Now the `mv` command is only run if the file exists.

The second way is if you don't care about the range, and just let the glob pattern match:

```
for f in LIB008983_TRA000*_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
do
  newName=${f/_*_\ _L001_R*.fastq.gz}
  mv -i "$f" "$newName"
done
```

In both cases you'll no longer try to `mv` files that don't exist.

As a side note; you don't need some of the `;` so I removed them from my answer.

You have a second problem, that your "$newName" isn't what you want.  I'm an oldschool `ksh` coder and there may be better `bash` expressions, but I'd do something like

```
  tail=L${f##*_L}
  head=${f%_*_$tail}_
  newName="$head$tail"
  mv -i "$f" "$newName"
```

So now given your input file list, we have

```
LIB008983_TRA00020080_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020080_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020081_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020081_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020082_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020082_L001_R2.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020083_L001_R1.fastq.gz
LIB008983_TRA00020083_L001_R2.fastq.gz
```

Comment: thank you Stephen, 

I've been playing around with the script according to your suggestions trying to get it to run, but I keep getting a syntax error. 

here's what I have:

'for f in LIB008983_TRA000{19916..20167}_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
if [-f "$f"]
then
        #mv -i "$f" "$newName"
        tail=L${f##*_L}
        head=${f%_*_$tail}
        newName="$head$tail"
#newName=${f/_*_\_L001_R*.fastq.gz}
  mv -i "$f" "$newName";'

error message: 
./og_rename.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
./og_rename.sh: line 5: `if [-f "$f"] '

Comment: for f in LIB008983_TRA000{19916..20167}_*_L001_R*.fastq.gz
if [-f "$f"]
then
        #mv -i "$f" "$newName"
        tail=L${f##*_L}
        head=${f%_*_$tail}
        newName="$head$tail"
#newName=${f/_*_\_L001_R*.fastq.gz}
  mv -i "$f" "$newName";

error message: 
./og_rename.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `if'
./og_rename.sh: line 5: `if [-f "$f"] '
I guess it has to do w/ if-then? 

edit: formatting in comments appears to be difficult for me.

Comment: It _looks_ like you're missing spaces around the `[` and `]`;  it should be `if [ -f "$f" ]` - those spaces are important.

Comment: just for clarification, here's the final script that worked:

for f in LIB008982_TRA000*_*_L002_R*.fastq.gz
do
 tail=L${f##*_L}
  head=${f%_*_$tail}_
  newName="$head$tail"
  mv -i "$f" "$newName"
done